# Web Application using GridView for CRUD form has multiple errors with GridView in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

so I followed this tutorial for creating a Web application using Gridview to perform CRUD in a Web form attached to a SQL database, and when I try to debug, there are 50+ errors saying that most of my items, including "GridView1" is not declared. Every time I try to use GridView, I have issues with errors. I am using VS 2012, and here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class VB
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        Me.BindGrid()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Customers_CRUD")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SELECT")
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt
                    GridView1.DataBind()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Protected Sub Insert(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim name As String = txtName.Text
    Dim country As String = txtCountry.Text
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Customers_CRUD")
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "INSERT")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", country)
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    Me.BindGrid()
End Sub

Protected Sub OnRowEditing(sender As Object, e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    Me.BindGrid()
End Sub

Protected Sub OnRowCancelingEdit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
    Me.BindGrid()
End Sub

Protected Sub OnRowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    Dim customerId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Values(0))
    Dim name As String = TryCast(row.FindControl("txtName"), TextBox).Text
    Dim country As String = TryCast(row.FindControl("txtCountry"), TextBox).Text
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Customers_CRUD")
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "UPDATE")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", customerId)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", country)
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
    Me.BindGrid()
End Sub

Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow AndAlso e.Row.RowIndex <> GridView1.EditIndex Then
        TryCast(e.Row.Cells(2).Controls(2), LinkButton).Attributes("onclick") = "return confirm('Do you want to delete this row?');"
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub OnRowDeleting(sender As Object, e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)
    Dim customerId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Values(0))
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Customers_CRUD")
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "DELETE")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", customerId)
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    Me.BindGrid()
  End Sub
 End Class



    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        table
        {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            width: 450px;
            margin-bottom: -1px;
        }
        table th
        {
            background-color: #F7F7F7;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        table th, table td
        {
            padding: 5px;
            border-color: #ccc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="CustomerId"
        OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="OnRowCancelingEdit"
        OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" EmptyDataText="No records has been added.">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true"
                ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 150px">
                Name:<br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="140" />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 150px">
                Country:<br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" Width="140" />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px">
                <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Insert" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change Partial Class VB to Partial Class _Default